# Mismatched anonymous define() modules when loading external scripts

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Yes, I know, this kind of question has been asked too many times.
But I have a small detail which I would like to clarify.

We have one script tag in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/js/app.87d28433.js" src="/js/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

We use requirejs api for loading googleTagManager:

```
require(["//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js"], function () { ... })
```

However we have no control on the scripts that GTM loads and how it loads them. So, in the end, we get a lot of scripts tags in the body which load scripts, like [FingerprintJS](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs/blob/master/fingerprint.js#L21), which declare anonymous define modules.

Is it possible in any way to bypass this behavior and keep requirejs **alive**?

Once again, we have no way to control what and how scripts are been loaded by GTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add error handler for require.js errors:

```
requirejs.onerror = function() {
    // do your error hadling stuff but don't throw exception!
}
```

(thanx to @maestro)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe that the answer is so simple :)

Comment: "Roman Bekkiev thank you so much man - probably saved me hours of debugging. The only thing I had to change was capitalizing the "E" (onError). Thanks again." - From another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073292/4099593)

Comment: It also helps to spell requirejs properly. :P